# Area Under Curve for Anomaly Detection

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, scikit-learn, roc, auc

I am performing Anomaly Detection using a CNN with a skew ratio of 1:9, and am using auc of the roc curve for evaluation of the model. The output of the CNN is a list of probabilities of positive and negative class. For predicting the label, I am also using a threshold of 0.1 for probabilities. For example,

```
if P(negative class) < threshold: then label = positive
```

To incorporate this threshold and evaluate the model, how should I call the roc_auc_score function of scikit-learn as it needs y_score parameter? What should the y_score parameter be?

```
roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, average=’macro’, sample_weight=None)
```

Comment: This is a programming question and should be moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It's not a programming question.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, that since this is anomaly detection problem, you have unlabeled data..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y_{score}$ is the continuous output of your classifier. In this case it sounds like the CNN is outputting a softmax, so it's just the value of the softmax at the class you are interested in.

I think there's some confusion. The ROC curve represents a *continuum* of thresholds. It makes no sense to request an ROC curve for a single threshold, because that just corresponds to a single point in ROC space (TP,FP).

On the other hand, the AUC is independent of threshold: it's the probability (with respect to your data distribution) that a positive class will rank above a negative class. This is the same regardless of threshold, since it references ground truth positive and negative, as opposed to predicted.

If you want to examine the TP,FP rates of each threshold, then you can make the call:

`fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_score)`

which will return vectors of false positive rates, true positive rates and corresponding thresholds.

Comment: But, since I am predicting the class w.r.t. a threshold, is treating the softmax output as y_score correct?

Comment: I've added edits that hopefully clarify your confusion.

Comment: @Hellboy Roughly speaking, AUC measures the performance of a classifier *averaged across all possible decision thresholds*, and that's why, as correctly pointed out in the answer (+1), it is threshold-independent; you may find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47104129/getting-a-low-roc-auc-score-but-a-high-accuracy/47111246#47111246) useful, too, in clarifying things.